# Dividing inline-block with <!-- --->

Tags: html, css

As you may know the hook with commenting whitespaces between 'display: inline-block' elements.

What do you think of such a solution:

```
    <div style="display:inline-block">Content 1</div><!--
---><div style="display:inline-block">Content 2</div><!--
---><div style="display:inline-block">Content 3</div>
```

I want to use '--->' in the end to keep code finely indentated without spaces ( I use four-digit tab ).

Also a question: in Sublime text 2 it does not understand that comment is closed with '--->' and paint all the code after as commented and does not highlight it. Is there an easy way around it?
Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally you only need two dashes to close a comment: `-->`

Comment: I guess he is using three dashes to line the divs up properly

Comment: @Tarilo But that’s dangerous because if he used more than two dashes the result can become invalid HTML. HTML comments are weird that way, two dashes within a comment end the comment.

Comment: You're right. I was just pointing out that the use of three dashes wasn't an accident but on purpose, this doesn't mean it's less wrong though.

Comment: I think this question is off topic, because you are basically reporting a bug with *Sublime Text 2*

Comment: That is not a bug, @rds, it should be a snippet highlighting setting and I wondered it should be edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the HTML 5 specification [on comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-comments):

> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (`<!--`). Following this sequence, the comment may have text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with a single U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (`>`), nor start with a "`-`" (U+002D) character followed by a U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (`>`) character, nor contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (`--`), **nor end with a "`-`" (U+002D) character**. Finally, the comment must be ended by the three character sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (`-->`).

You are ending the comment text with a `-` which is not allowed. This is confusing the syntax highlighter of your editor.

Using `-->` instead of `--->` will fix it. (I have tested this in my copy of subl2).

Answer (score 1):

For the effect you are trying to achieve, a neater solution is to use `float:left` on the elements. This is the exact situation float was designed for.
That way you remove the white space issue when using inline elements.

Comment: That is not the situation `float: left` was designed for. It was designed to allow text to wrap around images and asides. Floating left will have all sorts of potentially undesirable side effects, notably forcing everything to the left (it might be centred), breaking any vertical-align rules, and potentially causing weird stacking effectives if the boxes are not of equal height.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I was just wondering about the ---> as the end of comments. Inline-blocks are fine, too, and are an alternative for float:left.